# Need to display only description

Tags: php

I'm new to coding php, I had first a problem but someone on this site helped me thanks for that! I've fixed when you're on site.com/category.php you see all category's and when you on site.com/category.php?p=4 for like example you will see the same as on category.php but he only takes the ID.  I want now something else when i go to category.php?p=4 only description
here below is my code.

```
    <?php
include 'config.php';

// create a where clause
if (isset($_GET['p'])) $where="nameID=".(int)$_GET['p']; 
else $where=1;

// select all or specific using the where clause
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE ".$where;
$result = mysql_query($mysql);


// if there are rows returned
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    // iterate
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    {
    echo "" . $data['description'] . ""; //displays only when you're on category.php?p=4
    }
    // only want to display this on category.php
        echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?p=" . $data['nameID'] . "\"><b>" . $data['name'] . "</b></a> added on: " . $data['date'] . ", about this game <b>" . $data['description'] . "</b>";
    }
}else{
    echo 'Nothing to find here';
}
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` library is **deprecated**. You should move onto `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. These have a lot of documentation.

Comment: What are you getting? Or what error message are you getting?

Comment: there is no error, only a small problem.  echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?p=" . $data['nameID'] . "\"><b>" . $data['name'] . "</b></a> added on: " . $data['date'] . ", about this game <b>" . $data['description'] . "</b>";
is on every page which I won't, just want that code to show up only on category.php and $description only on category.php?p=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you need / mean if not please comment so that I can edit it:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$id = $_GET['p']; //get the p (id) from the url

//check if the p (id) is in the url and not empty
if(isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
    //the query
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `nameID` = '$id'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count >= 1) {
        while($associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo $associate['description'];
        }
    }
} else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category`");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count >= 1) {
        while($associate = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '<li><a href="category.php?p='.$associate['nameID'].'"><b>'.$associate['name'].'</b></a> added on: '.$associate['date'].', about this game <b>'.$associate['description'].'</b>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'nothing found';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if($count >= 1) {, I get only 1 from database on category.php I need all rows thank you

Answer (score 0):

check your select query
`$mysql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE ".$where;`

It is incomplete.

It should be like

`` `$mysql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id like '$where' ``

or

`` `$mysql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id ='$where' ``

Comment: I don't think thats not the problem, I get everything what I need from the database but the only thing which I need is that this code:

`code`echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?p=" . $data['nameID'] . "\"><b>" . $data['name'] . "</b></a> added on: " . $data['date'] . ", about this game <b>" . $data['description'] . "</b>"; `code`

only shows on the page category.php, and not on category.php?p=4 for example. on category I want only the description

Comment: ,just try pass the $_get data to a variable and then use it.. As done by @user3390200 .

Answer (score 0):

Use if statements on whether the `p` URL parameter is set.

Put the parts you only want to display on the category.php?p=... pages in

`if(isset($_GET['p']))`

and the parts you want to display on the category.php page in

`if(!isset($_GET['p']))`

You should also look to replace mysql with mysqli or PDO, and if you are using the `<b>` tags for styling you should replace these with `<span style='font-weight:bold'>`